# Entity Framework Core connection error to SQL Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I want to run an example project (Contoso University) in VS 2015 Community with SQL Express 2016 database but the login is failed with my user.
I can connect from the VS Server Explorer and I copied the connection string into the *appsettings.json* but no msuch success.

Connection string:

> "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity1;Integrated Security=True"

Error message:

> Cannot open database "ContosoUniversity1" requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user 'username'.

Hm? :)

Comment: Are you have set the appropriate permissions to the user? If you using Integrated Security=True , it's mean you want to use Windows Authentication, You need administrator rights on the database.

Comment: Yes I have sysadmin role and I could connect to it from VS Server Explorer and I have this dependency in the project.json: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1"

Comment: You have  done Migration properly?  Try run first migration from command prompt, after that you should connect without errors.

Comment: No, I haven't. I check it. Thx.

Comment: If it  help you, put some information.